# How do I get the button to listen to the segmented control in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, button, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a temperature converter app. I used the segmented control for users to select how the temperature should be calculated (Celsius to Fahrenheit and from Fahrenheit to Celsius). I've also created a button that would convert the temperature entered by the selected method in the segmented control.

Here's the function I've created in the controller:

```
@IBAction func convertTemp(sender: AnyObject) {
    let t = Double(tempTextfield.text!)
    let type = converterType.selectedSegmentIndex
    let tempM = tempModel(temp:t!)

    if type == 0 {
        finalTemp.text = String(tempM.celsius2Fahrenheit())
    }

    if type == 1 {
        finalTemp.text = String(tempM.fahrenheit2Celsius())
    }
}
```

And here's what I have in my model.

```
class tempModel {
  var temp: Double

  init (temp:Double){
    self.temp = temp
  }
  func celsius2Fahrenheit()->Double{
    return 32 + temp * 5 / 9;
  }
  func fahrenheit2Celsius()->Double{
    return (temp - 32) * 5/9;  
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Everything but the `Button(convert)` works the way I want it to work. I can't seem to find the error.

And I don't know if this helps but I get this error:

> 2015-11-16 18:07:02.496 TemperatureConverer[5201:194432] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 4131139949_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>   2015-11-16 18:07:04.827 TemperatureConverer[5201:194432] Can't find keyplane that supports type 8 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-DecimalPad; using 4131139949_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>   (lldb)

Comment: Did you try printing `Double(tempTextfield.text!)`

Comment: yeah, I just tried printing Double(tempTextfield.text!) and its not printing.

Comment: so, the problem is with `tempTextfield.text!`. Try to print it and you can see optional keyword it. you have to unwrap it safely before casting it to Double.

Comment: oh okay Ill work on it. thanks

Comment: you might also consider extending your String to get double value as follows `var doubleValue:Double? {
        return NumberFormatter.instance.numberFromString(self)?.doubleValue
    }`

Answer (score 2):

I found a temporary fix. My problem was communication between  my viewController and my tempModel.  My code worked when I removed the tempModel class and inserting the method directly into the function in my controller. 
So in my controller, I have this..

```
@IBAction func convertTemp(sender: AnyObject) {

    let temp = Double(tempTextfield.text!)!
    var newTemp = ""

    if converterType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
        newTemp = String(format: "%.2f Farenheit", 32+temp*5/9)
    }
    if converterType.selectedSegmentIndex == 1{
        newTemp = String(format: "%.2f Celsius",(temp-32)*5/9)
    }
    finalTemp.text = newTemp
}
```

I know eventually I would have to learn how to link my controller and model together .  But until I figure it out, this is one solution that fixed my problem.